# Induction proof $n^2 < 2^n$ for $n > 4$

Tags: induction

I need to prove that $n^2 < 2^n$ for all natural numbers $n$ greater than $4$.

I understand that you start by proving the base case of $n = 5$ and then prove the inequality substituting the inductive hypothesis for $n + 1$, but I am unsure about how to do this.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Proof that $n^2<2^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/319913/462).

Answer (score 3):

$$ 2^{x+1} = 2^x2 > 2x^2 = x^2 + x^2 > x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x + 1)^2 $$

Second inequality from the left follows from the induction hypothesis. And we get desired result if we can show $x^2 > 2x + 1$ for $x > 4$. but That is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Putting in a couple extra steps for clarity, once $n\gt4$, we have

$$\begin{align}
2^{n+1}&=2\cdot2^n\cr
&\gt2\cdot n^2\quad\text{ (by the induction hypothesis)}\cr
&=n^2+n^2\cr
&\gt n^2+n\cdot3\quad\text{ (since $n\gt3$)}\cr
&\gt n^2+n\left(2+{1\over n}\right)\quad\text{ (since $n\gt1$)}\cr
&=n^2+2n+1\cr
&=(n+1)^2
\end{align}$$