# Proof that $ k^2<2^k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, induction, divisibility

I'm struggling with this problem of proof by induction:

> For any natural number $k\geq 5$, prove that  $k^2<2^k$.

I assumed that $k^2<2^k$

I want to show that $(k+1)^2<2^{k+1}$

The final statement is $k^2+2k+1$

Am I missing something ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319913/proof-that-n2-2n

Comment: Thanks, @lab. This question has been asked more times that I can begin to count!

Comment: Yes, you are missing some things: You need to consider the  *base case*: Show the proposition is true for $k = 5$, and secondly, you haven't shown that $(k+1)^2 = k^2 + 2k + 1 \lt 2^{k+1} = 2\cdot 2^k$.