# I tried to prove but I confused. Can you help me, please?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Prove by induction:

$2^n\ge n^2$ for all $n\ge 5$.

Comment: You say you tried. Please edit the question to show us everything you did.

Comment: This may help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319913/proof-that-n2-2n

Comment: As an aside, your tags and title used for the question should reflect what the question is actually about.  If someone only looked at your title, they wouldn't have a clue what your question is, just that you have one.  If they looked at your tag and saw "theorem-provers" they'd think it was about Mizar or some other computer software that assists in writing/checking proofs.  Use a descriptive title and use appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

Well your first step should be to prove it when n = 5. This will be your base case scenario. From there you need to prove it for n = k + 1. Simply plug in k + 1 for n in your equation (2^n >= n^2). Your new equation will be (2^(k+1) >= (k+1)^2). Simply step through the algebra at this point.